# MATLAB GUI User Input Update

Tags: matlab, user-interface, input

I have a MATLAB GUI which takes values from the user input , do some calculation based on those and plot them in the GUI.

Everything is all right and working BUT when I change the values in the GUI it does not plot as expected and gives and error of dimension mismatch. However, there is no dimension mismatch and if I go to the script and press run again (the big green arrow) and then click plot again, it plots the values as expected.

I have initialized all of my values that I use but I can not see how can fix this. I need something like update command for all of the script each time I press the 'plot' button.

Any help is appreciated, many thanks!..

CODE:

```
a = str2double(get(handles.edit14,'String'));
b = str2double(get(handles.edit15,'String'));
c = str2double(get(handles.edit16,'String'));
d = str2double(get(handles.edit18,'String'));
e = str2double(get(handles.edit19,'String')); 
f = str2double(get(handles.edit20,'String'));

for Veff=[a:b:c] %user input speeds (a,b,c) (comes from user)
q = 0.5*1.225*(Veff*1000/3600)^2; 
F1=q*S; M1=q*S*Cref;
FX1=(F1*coef(:,1));  FZ1=(F1*coef(:,3)); MM1=(M1*coef(:,5));
 W=[d*g:e*g:f*g];  %define mass range (d,e,f comes from user)
 for lw=1:1:length(W)
XGEquation2max1 = ((((-FB*(Xa-Xb))-(((FX1(12)))*(Za-Zr))-(((FZ1(7))))*(Xa-Xr))-((max(MM1))))./W(lw)) + Xa;
CGPercent(lw,column) = (XGEquation2max1 - Cstart)/Cref * 100;

 end
 column=column+1;
end

speed_matrix = [a:b:c];
mass_matrix = [d:e:f];
ns = size(speed_matrix);
ns= ns(2);
count5 = 1;
for ns=1:1:ns
hold all
axes(handles.axes4) 
plot(CGPercent(:,ns),transpose(mass_matrix)/1000)
count5 = count5 + 1;
end
```

Main problem is with the variables 'd,e,f' because when I change 'a,b,c' only (i.e speed) there is no problem.

Comment: I'm afraid we need more that that to fix the problem. Can you post the code you use that does not work? Simple check: do you use the handles structure with guidata(hObject,handles) to update it for instance?

Comment: Yes I have added 'guidata(hObject,handles)' but it does not work really. I have updated my post to have the code as well.

Comment: Where do 'd','e' and 'f' come from? How/where are they stored?

Comment: They come from the User in the GUI. They are not stored. I only get them every time by using; 

a = str2double(get(handles.edit14,'String'));
b = str2double(get(handles.edit15,'String'));
c = str2double(get(handles.edit16,'String'));

(same for d,e,f) All of them are numbers.

Comment: When you say you 'change values in the GUI it does not plot as expected' is it inside a callback? A pushbutton for example?

Comment: Values that I enter is in an editbox and to process them them there is a pushbutton. I have found out that the problem is: CGPercent is not updating itself as a,b,c,d,e,f are doing. Thats why a mismatch in the dimension occurs. When I press run again CGPercent getting re-calculated and then it works..

Comment: ok so is your problem solved? I'm not sure I follow haha sorry.

Comment: So you know how to solve the problem then? I think that you need to update CGPercent in a callback function, but you may have realized that too?

Comment: Actually CGPercent was not initialized by a mistake. Now every time I click calculate it becomes 0 and then the value given by the user. Thanks